# most optimized way to select "flagged posts" using where & limit in mysql database

Tags: database-design, mysql, query-optimization, spam-prevention

I have the following table structure:

```
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+------------------------------------------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                   | Null | Key | Default                                  | Extra          |
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+------------------------------------------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned       | NO   | PRI | NULL                                     | auto_increment |
| body     | varchar(200)           | NO   |     | Hey now!                                 |                |
| flags    | int(10) unsigned       | NO   |     | 0                                        |                |
| views    | int(10) unsigned       | NO   |     | 1                                        |                |
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

and I want to select "only rows that have not been flagged more than 5% of their total views, and have been viewed at least 5 times."

Here is my query:

```
SELECT id,body
FROM tablename
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM tablename
    WHERE flags/views * 100 > 5.0
    AND views > 5
    ORDER BY id DESC
)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 6
```

I'm thinking that selecting "every single row that has been flagged more than 30% of total views" is going to be a ton of overhead, especially when the table grows to a very large number of rows. Could someone please help me optimize this?

I was also thinking of creating a "flag_score" column and just updating that each time something is flagged, that way I could just select on the flag_score column instead of doing the math within the select (and save myself the extra select query). Does that sound like a good approach? Thanks a bunch.

Edit: The other problem I was having is that if I simply do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabelname
WHERE flags/views * 100 > 5.0
AND views > 5
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

... if 4 out of the 5 posts have been flagged, it will only return 1 row! And I'd like the statement to return 5 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The math is not very expensive, so as long as you have less than, say, 100 000 entries, you can do it like this with no worry.

As suggested by yourself you can always cache the condition:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET is_over_30_percent = (flags/views * 100 > 5.0)
WHERE id='id_of_updated_entry'
```

which has the advantage that you can put an index on *is_over_30_percent* so the query takes no performance at all.

Remember to put a combined index on *id_of_updated_entry* **and** *date* and *id* so the index can be used for selecting and ordering (ORDER BY is expensive).

Comment: Oh, by the way: If you're concerned about performance, try to avoid the subselect. Do it in your procedural language if you must have it. MySQL is very bad at optimizing them.

Comment: thanks! i thought order by was pretty expensive but i wasn't sure.

Comment: so that would be storing is_over_30_percent as a boolean (aka tinyint)? that sounds like a good idea! i was just thinking of storing the actual score (ie 5, or 10, or 0, etc) but if it's just a boolean that seems cleaner! thanks!

Comment: Exactly. If you don't need the score, why store it. It's just a cache, so you can always change it later, should you need the actual score.

Comment: awesome, and since i'll be doing updates anyhow when it's flagged, that will be fine. thanks.

Comment: one more quick question - would it be worth it to do a "SELECT COUNT(*) ... WHERE flags/views > 0.05" before the UPDATE so that it doesn't constantly set the is_over_30_percent field to 0?

Comment: You mean to find out if any entries must be changed? No, that would not work, because it won't find entries that need to be set to 0 because they dropped below that threshold. Furthermore an UPDATE that changes nothing is nearly the same as a SELECT. (MySQL filters away useless write access.)

Answer (score 0):

I would say caching is a reasonable approach, but it all depends on what the read/writes are like in your system.  If people are flagging all of the time, then the flag_score value will need to be updated each time, so your expensive operation will be happening a lot.

Separately, I am not sure if you will get a performance boost, but you could do flag/views > .05 to save the multiplication each query, although I wouldn't expect that part to be that expensive.

Comment: that's sort of tbd i guess, but i don't expect them to be too crazy. thanks on saving the multiplication. can't hurt!